# Is there any library to create a uniformly random unitary matrix?

Tags: qiskit, pennylane

Is there any library to create a random special unitary $SU(N)$ that generates from Haar distribution? I understand in PennyLane there is `qml.SpecialUnitary` function but it provides imaginary parameters. I would like to generate real parameters which is $4^n -1 $ parameters are possible.

Comment: You mean you want to call a function that takes no parameter and samples a Haar-random unitary? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: (Except the dimension of course)

Comment: It will take parameters. For example, SU(N) special unitary requires $4^n - 1$ parameters where N = 2^n., n is a number of qubits. I want that number of parameters

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Pennylane function you've mentioned does not sample from the Haar measure. It uses the parameters you give to create a matrix, but no sampling is involved. This is what I fail to understand in your question. What would your parameters control in this function? In the Pennylane one, they control the Pauli coefficients of a matrix that will then be exponentiated to be in $SU(N)$.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica this is done with the [command](https://wolfram.com/xid/0vu21qkgdsp0u7l9n52-lcf25m)
`RandomVariate[CircularUnitaryMatrixDistribution[N]]`, as the Haar measure for U(N) is known as the [Circular Unitary Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_ensemble).